# How to change this code /proc/meminfo from kb to mb/gb?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I got right now this in the code

```
`cat /proc/meminfo | 
   grep MemFree | 
   awk {'print $2'}`kB (Free) / `cat /proc/meminfo | 
   grep MemTotal | 
   awk {'print $2'}`kB (Total)
```

Comment: OK, I should not have edited your question.  The original command you posted was not working, (syntax errors), the edited is also not working.... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ numfmt --field 2 --from-unit=Ki --to=iec --format="%.2f" --suffix=b </proc/meminfo |
    awk '/MemFree/{print $2 " (Free) "} /MemTotal/{print $2 " (Total) "}'
3.29Gb (Total) 
2.75Gb (Free)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what do you ask for but also worth to consider:

```sh
free -h
free -h --mega
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep MemFree /proc/meminfo
```

output: `MemFree:        15932276 kB`

```
echo $(expr $(awk '/MemFree/{ print $2 }' /proc/meminfo) / 1)
```

output: `15932268`

```
echo $(expr $(awk '/MemFree/{ print $2 }' /proc/meminfo) / 1024) Mb
```

output: `15558 Mb`

```
echo $(expr $(awk '/MemFree/{ print $2 }' /proc/meminfo) / 1024 / 1024) Gb
```

output: `15 Gb`

- see [man expr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expr)
- Also you used backquotes around a statement. It better to use `$(...)`  (The best reason is that it will not interfere with stackoverflow formatting )

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Alex Cumarav's answer: You can parse the total amount of memory from `free`'s output with `awk` rather easily:

`free --mega | awk -e '/^Mem:/ { print $2}'`

Instead of the `--mega` option which gives you megabytes, you can also use `--giga`, etc. Check out the manpage `man free` for all the possibilities.